# Abandoned Live Agent Chat still creats a Case?

Tags: liveagent, embedded-services

When a user abandons a chat request, a case is still getting created.  Here is an example timeline:

- Chat requested at 08:36:37 (`LiveChatTranscript.RequestTime`)
- Chat abandoned by visitor 30 seconds later, at 08:37:07. (`LiveChatTranscript.EndTime`, `LiveChatTranscript.Abandoned` = 30)
- The associated Case was created 5 seconds later, at 08:37:12 by `Automated Process`.

We are using the Embedded Service Chat prechat settings to pre-populate some fields and link the records, including some Case fields.  Some of the data is being supplied by the external system where the chat is hosted, so we use this mapping to ensure all the external data is synced to the right fields.  Not sure if this is the cause, but if it is, I don't see how to make it conditional.  Shouldn't there be some way to skip Case Creation if a chat request is abandoned?  Here are the prechat settings:

```
embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatInfo = [{
    "entityName": "Account",
    "showOnCreate": true,
    "linkToEntityName":  "Contact",
    "linkToEntityField": "AccountId",
    "saveToTranscript": "AccountId",
    "entityFieldMaps": [{
        "isExactMatch": false,
        "fieldName": "Name",
        "doCreate": true,
        "doFind": false,
        "label": "Provider Name"
    }, {
        "isExactMatch": true,
        "fieldName": "Customer_ID_Acct__c",
        "doCreate": true,
        "doFind": true,
        "label": "Provider Code"
    }]
}, {
    "entityName": "Contact",
    "showOnCreate": true,
    "linkToEntityName": "Case",
    "linkToEntityField": "ContactId",
    "saveToTranscript": "ContactId",
    "entityFieldMaps": [{
        "fieldName": "FirstName",
        "doCreate": true,
        "doFind": false,
        "isExactMatch": false,
        "label": "First Name"
    }, {
        "fieldName": "LastName",
        "doCreate": true,
        "doFind": false,
        "isExactMatch": false,
        "label": "Last Name"
    }, {
        "fieldName": "Email",
        "doCreate": true,
        "doFind": false,
        "isExactMatch": false,
        "label": "Email"
    }, {
        "fieldName": "Contact_Segmentation__c",
        "doCreate": true,
        "doFind": false,
        "isExactMatch": false,
        "label": "Contact Segmentation"
    }, {
        "fieldName": "System_Username__c",
        "doCreate": true,
        "doFind": false,
        "isExactMatch": false,
        "label": "System Username"
    },{
        "fieldName": "Contact_Unique_ID__c",
        "doCreate": false,
        "doFind": true,
        "isExactMatch": true,
        "label": "Contact Unique ID"
    }],
}, {
    "entityName": "Case",
    "showOnCreate": true,
    "saveToTranscript": "CaseId",
    "entityFieldMaps": [{
        "isExactMatch": false,
        "fieldName": "RecordTypeId",
        "doCreate": true,
        "doFind": false,
        "label": "CaseRecordTypeId"
    }, {
        "isExactMatch": false,
        "fieldName": "Subject",
        "doCreate": true,
        "doFind": false,
        "label": "Subject"
    }, {
        "isExactMatch": false,
        "fieldName": "Status",
        "doCreate": true,
        "doFind": false,
        "label": "Status"
    }, {
        "isExactMatch": false,
        "fieldName": "Origin",
        "doCreate": true,
        "doFind": false,
        "label": "Origin"
    }, {
        "isExactMatch": false,
        "fieldName": "System_Live_Chat_Login_ID__c",
        "doCreate": true,
        "doFind": false,
        "label": "System Live Chat Login ID"
    }, {
        "isExactMatch": false,
        "fieldName": "Environment__c",
        "doCreate": true,
        "doFind": false,
        "label": "Environment"
    }, {
        "isExactMatch": false,
        "fieldName": "Contact_Super_Admin__c",
        "doCreate": true,
        "doFind": false,
        "label": "Contact Super Admin"
    }, {
        "isExactMatch": false,
        "fieldName": "Contact_Inactive__c",
        "doCreate": true,
        "doFind": false,
        "label": "Contact Inactive"
    }]
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working as designed behavior.

You can try using Omni-flow with your Embedded Service Chat configuration. Omni-flow allows you to route based on pre-chat data, which means you can add conditional logic based on pre-chat data as well. Or you can run a batch job to delete the Cases associated with abandoned Chats.